# What are some beginning guides for a fingerstyle acoustic guitarist?

Tags: acoustic-guitar

I just started playing the guitar in the past few months with no influence but decided now was a good time to research into this and improve by observation along with practice. I practice about twice a day every day for 30 min+ so what are some key things to look out for when first starting?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're already learning the technical building blocks like the main types of chord fingerings and the simple scales, my own musical development was always fastest when I was playing (or trying to play) the main riffs from simple songs that I like. I would just search online for "songname guitar tab" whenever an earworm got lodged in my head, and slowly try to work through the notes until I got comfortable enough to improvise on it a bit. For fingerpicking some of my favorites were the Beatles - Blackbird, Kansas - Dust in the Wind, Zeppelin - Stairway, Clapton - Tears in Heaven.

Comment: Be warned! There are a lot of inaccurate/poor tabs out there which won't help your progress much. Rely on your ears, they will improve, and in turn help your playing improve.

Comment: I hope you are at least using a tutorial book.  It should set you straight with hand and seating position and stuff like that.  There are plenty of good books out there that would suit the type of guitar playing you are interested in.  Of course it goes without saying that it'd be helpful to get a teacher, although much can be achieved with a good tutorial book on your own if you follow it carefully.

Comment: +1 @Tim that's an important point, tabs are very hit or miss and best treated as untrustworthy crutches. Listening actively to the song until you can sing/hum along is a must, and trust your instincts!

Comment: Maybe shouldn't ask this, but for me knowing a little background about contributors helps. Maybe the profile?